# How can i change the language of my Html5 hybrid application using java script and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

In my application i have a option of language selection.

When I select an option, the entire application language should be changed.

I have already tried using Google and Microsoft api but guess that is paid. Is there any free api using javascript that can help me regarding this problem.

Comment: Please.. no automated translation services. They are usually horrible (even though they greatly improved in the last years). If you have customers in country X, get somebody who speaks both languages **and** is experienced with whatever your app is about to translate it.

Comment: -1. Because of a strong suspicion of. This is not how you do it. (You have to do something more complicated I think).

Comment: @OlofEdler - See I have a hybrid -ipad application where i have to implement multilanguage support. This means that i give the user an option of selecting a language from the drop down where accordingly the application will change into that language. This is all I want to do. I hope I have made my question clearer .

Comment: I thought (I'm no expert) you had to add a php script and mix with the session or so. Hope someone will upvote your question.

Comment: @RajNahil: Have you seen what it can do to text? This is a *bad* idea. You should tell your client that you need the resources to do the translations.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

**#1**
Have a look [here](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/). Click "Options" top right and select another langauges. Open a datebox plugin widget and it will be in the language you specified.

I like the way it's done using [Crowdin](https://crowdin.com/project/jquery-mobile-datebox), although you will end up with all your text in .js files. If you check out one of the [languages sample files](http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i18n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.en_US.utf8.js) this will be a lot of meat to load if your site becomes more complex.

**#2**
Do this server side. I'm (using Coldfusion) loading a langauge object on first page load and cache this until the user selects a new language. My langauge object is about 60k with 2000 entries. You could also send this to the page from server via json and store it in the page, then you could reference it from Jquery/Javascript.

I will probably end up trying to switch from server side to using the first approach and will try to see if I can split up my language .js files according to JQM page and then load them together with [require](http://requirejs.org/), which would mean only a few ks per page. If you don't mind having a bunch of langauge files for each language and page, this would probably be the best "Mobile" approach.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9781124/language-switcher-link-changes-url) might be what you are looking for. They are talking about:

- A `wordpress`, change language `plugin widget`.
- A `jQuery handler` to change language `by directing to another url`.

Have a nice day!